# How to mark invalid values/inputs with Editor, EditorDriver

Tags: java, validation, gwt, bean-validation

I'm following tutorials on GWT Project website, namely sections [Editors](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html) and [Validation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideValidation.html), and it's not clear to me what is the proper approach when one wants **to mark the inputs that failed during the validation**...?
I don't expect any sort of constraintViolation.mark() method, rather some link from the validation error to its related Element so I can display an error message next to it.

I guess I could find the inputs within the DOM on my own using the (property) path of the constraintViolation, but that doesn't sound right as I would need to mark their respective elements beforehand. (Also that does not deal with list of sub-editors.)

I feel like EditorDriver should somehow help me handle this but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [`EditorDriver#setConstraintViolations`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/EditorDriver.html#setConstraintViolations%28java.lang.Iterable%29)? The `EditorDriver` will match the constraint violations to the editors and will dispatch the errors to the [`HasEditorErrors`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/HasEditorErrors.html) in the editor hierarchy.